# Как добиться того, чтобы find показывал не индекс первого появления символа, а последнего?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Как добиться того, чтобы find показывал не индекс первого появления символа, а последнего? Может есть что то кроме find?

```
a = "поезд_поезд_поезд"
print(a.find("е"))
```

Answer (score 2):

[str.rfind](https://pythonz.net/references/named/str.rfind/):

```py
a = "поезд_поезд_поезд"
print(a.rfind("е")) # 14
```

Answer (score 2):

Есть `rfind` для этого:

```
a = "поезд_поезд_поезд"
print(a.rfind("е"))

14
```